# Is "ich mag zu esse" right?

Tags: english-to-german, german-to-english

I had seen an almost native-speaker of german saying that, I would like to know if that is grammar right.
  The original sentence is "Ich mag meinen Arsch zu rasieren"

Ich mag zu esse -> I like to eat

Comment: The word means "eat", and the grammar is totally wrong.

Comment: Karl, I am sorry, it was "eat".

Comment: "to eat" is not giving a direction in english, but is the *infinitive*. What is the resp. German infinitive?

Comment: I don't want to know where you heard that, but it should either be "Ich mag es, meinen Arsch zu rasieren" (a general statement) or "ich mag meinen Arsch rasieren" (you'd like to do it *now*). Jedem Tierchen sein Pläsierchen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of possible options with *mögen*.

> 1. Ich mag Essen/Pizza/deinen Bruder. (+ Akkusativ)
> 2. Ich mag (es), wenn die Sonne scheint. (+ Satz; *es* can be omitted)
>    Ich mag es, in der Sonne zu liegen. (+ Infinitivkonstruktion; *es* obligatory)
> 3. Ich mag nicht mehr laufen. (+ Infinitiv; only negative, meaning "keine Lust haben")
> 4. Das mag stimmen. (+ Infinitiv; meaning "möglich sein")

Your example is quite close to something based on the first option.

> Ich brauch (et)was zu essen. / Ich brauch (et)was zum Essen.
> "Ich brauche etwas, das man essen kann."

Note that the final *-n* of infinitives is dropped in certain dialects, so *essen* can become *esse*.

However, I find the sentence *Ich mag was zu esse(n)* (with the presumed meaning of "Ich hätte gern etwas zu essen") quite bad. It might acceptable in certain dialects, though.

Answer (score 1):

No. But you can say "ich mag **es**, zu essen"

Comment: Does it means the same?

Comment: You can. But wouldn't "Ich esse gerne" be more idiomatic?